# VSCode as Git editor on Windows Subsystem for linux (WSL)

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, commit-message

## Context

#### System Information (Windows)

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.17134 N/A Build 17134
...
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 10 GenuineIntel ~3696 Mhz
BIOS Version:              American Megatrends Inc. 2.20, 10/27/2017
```

#### System Information (WSL)

```
OS: Debian
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft
Shell: zsh 5.3.1
CPU: Intel Core i7-8700K CPU @ 3.696GHz
RAM: 8041MiB / 16344MiB
```

#### Git

I have this in my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[core]
    editor = code --wait
```

## Problem:

When I run `git commit`, vscode starts with `C:\mnt\$PathToRepo$\.git\COMMIT_EDITMSG`, but this file is empty (it's supposed to have changes to be commited + a diff).

And when I write a commit message, save and exit, I get this in the terminal:

```
Aborting commit due to empty commit message.
```

**Note**:

when i do this:

1. run `git commit`;
2. write commit message in vscode (ex: *Initialize repo*), save and close;
3. after the `Aborting commit due to empty commit message.`, i run `git commit` again;

VSCode will open with the same commit message i wrote in step 2 (ie: *Initialize repo*)

Comment: I can at least confirm that I see the same thing.  I'm using wslgit from https://github.com/andy-5/wslgit, but that doesn't seem to help in any way.  The problem is likely due to tmp file handling on linux vs windows, I imagine?  I'll watch for answers here :)

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/27101 <--could be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the whole point is to to use WSL git on vscode, here is the official solution: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl.

Essentially, you just need to install the [Remote Development Extension Pack](https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/download/extension).

Answer (score 5):

Currently, VSCode can be used as a Git editor by leveraging `vscode-server` running in WSL. To configure it, simply and add the following lines to your `~/.gitconfig` file in WSL:

```ini
[core]
    editor = code --wait
```

If it still doesn't work, please make sure that your `vscode-server` has been added to the environment variables. Run `which code` in shell, it should give output like

```bash
/home/user/.vscode-server/bin/4cb974a7aed77a74c7813bdccd99ee0d04901215/bin/remote-cli/code
```

---

`vscode-server` also works with a remote Linux instance. Thanks for [Karol Zlot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8896457/karol-zlot)

Comment: This works also when using Ubuntu VM as remote host, not only WSL.

Answer (score 1):

On trying things more this solution works: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/27101#issuecomment-306994732

The whole problem is translating the location of the file for Windows.  Using a script such as the one linked to there (https://github.com/Milly/wslpath) with a wrapper script will allow the message to correctly open in vscode.  I personally removed the -n option in my wrapper script because I prefer a tab.